# Lock screen shortcut not working after update of Fedora 16

Tags: fedora, screensaver, screen-lock

I recently ran a bunch of updates (I didn't pay attention to which, I was just prompted to update a bunch of stuff), and after running them, the lock-screen shortcut (CTRL-Alt-L) no longer works. I tried modifying the keyboard shortcut in the keyboard system settings to no avail. Does anyone know what the problem might be or how I can find out?

Comment: New updates haven't been produced for Fedora 16 for about a year; did you mean 18 or 19? Or did you have a system sitting there without updates and vintage F16 updates still hadn't been applied? (I'm not judging, just making sure!)

Comment: Yes, vintage F16 updates had not been applied, and I finally applied them. I fixed this by running `gnome-screensaver &`, since I guess this was removed from a list of startup apps. It's not ideal because I have to run that each time I restart or manually put it in my login file (seems like I should not have to do this).

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the ability to lock the screen is still enabled in GNOME. You can do this using the `gconf-editor` tool. After launching it go to the following menu item "lockdown" under this branch in the tree:

> / → desktop → gnome → lockdown

Once in the "lockdown" leaf node of the tree you can enable/disable the ability to lock the screen. The item is "disable_lock_screen".